# "Potentially excessive number of SPRequest objects" coming from Microsoft's own code?

Tags: dispose

In one of my SharePoint apps, I am getting this warning & stacktrace over and over (with different GUIDS): since it's only one of my apps, I assume there's something in my project's code, but SPDisposeCheck returns clean, and there's nothing in the logs that point to my code.

Any ideas on how I can track this down?

**Error I'm getting:**

> Potentially excessive number of
>   SPRequest objects (9) currently
>   unreleased on thread 1. Ensure that
>   this object or its parent (such as an
>   SPWeb or SPSite) is being properly
>   disposed. Allocation Id for this
>   object:
>   {1DFFC1ED-E69E-4580-8D7B-45EDB5C49188}

Stack trace of current allocation:

```
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.Add(SPRequest request, Boolean shareable)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureSPRequest()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Request()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetFileOrFolderProperties(String strUrl, ListDocsFlags listDocsFlags, Boolean throwException)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.PropertiesCore(Boolean throwException)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_Properties()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_Level()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleXmlUtilities.configFile(String myUniqueId, SPFileLevel level)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleXmlUtilities.ConfigurationXml(String configProvider, Boolean isBuiltInConfigFile)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleXmlUtilities.GetConsoleNodeCollection(String configXml, ConsoleNode prePopulatedRootNode)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleXmlUtilities.GetConsoleNodeCollection(String configXml)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleXmlUtilities.GetConsoleNodeCollectionFromXmlFile(String configName, Boolean isBuiltInConfigFile)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.XmlConsoleDataSource.LoadTreeFromConfigXml()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.XmlConsoleDataSource.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.ForceInitLoad(EventArgs e)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.PublishingSiteActionsMenuCustomizer.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning "Potentiallt excessive number of SPRequest objects.." you get in ULS log could be or could not be an issue.

This warning does not necessarily indicate your objects are not being disposed, just that you have opened alot of them (like when doing a loop through current webs). This warning can be mitigated by setting up the treshold to a larger value:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\HeapSettings

    LocalSPRequestWarnCount = 50
```

You should however monitor the ULS log for 8l1n An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread. This is usually a sign of a memory leak in the code (MS or custom).

further reading:
[Troubleshooting SPSite/SPWeb leaks in WSS v3 and MOSS 2007](http://blogs.technet.com/stefan%5Fgossner/archive/2008/05/07/troubleshooting-spsite-spweb-leaks-in-wss-v3-and-moss-2007.aspx)

hth
Anders Rask

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been answered before: check [Warning of undisposed objects in Microsoft's own SharePoint code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/warning-of-undisposed-objects-in-microsofts-own-sharepoint-code)  
In short, that answer is "yes it may happen and nothing much to do about it"

Comment: Well kind of. Its related to the answer Steve gives, but not to the question (which is related to undisposed objects).

Comment: There is a subtle difference to these questions. The question you've linked to Emad is "An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread" and this question is "Potentially excessive number of SPRequest objects".