# Showing all newform.aspx of a certain content type in a dynamic list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list, content-type, content-query-web-part

How can I provide the following solution?

- on the 'home page' of a site collection, query all lists with a certain content type ('eForms')
- each list entry will be a link to the 'newform.aspx' of that particular list

I find that currently we are manually maintaining a list to all of our eForms which is becoming quite cumbersome.  We do have the ability to apply content types to these lists so a CQWP or otherwise can 'latch onto' them and pull it.  The problem is, I don't want the individual items within the list to appear on the CQWP, but rather need to just link to the "newform.aspx" so users can easily navigate to submit new form data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution in C# (assuming that you'll use the code in a visual webpart):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var eForms = new List<EForm>();
        foreach (SPWeb web in SPContext.Current.Site.AllWebs)
        {
            var listsWithWantedContentType = web.Lists.Cast<SPList>()
                .Where(list => list.ContentTypes.Cast<SPContentType>()
                .Any(ct => ct.Name == "Item"));
            foreach (var list in listsWithWantedContentType)
            {
                eForms.Add(new EForm
                               {
                                   ListUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                   ListTitle = list.Title,
                                   NewFormUrl = list.DefaultNewFormUrl
                               });                    
            }

            web.Dispose();
        }
        gvLists.DataSource = eForms;
        gvLists.DataBind();
    }

    class EForm
    {
        public string ListUrl { get; set; }
        public string ListTitle { get; set; }
        public string NewFormUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

gvList is a GridView control that you'll put inside the webpart ascx control.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLists" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I disagree. See here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/disposal-of-spwebs-retrieved-from-spcontext-current-site-allwebs

Comment: @MdMazzotti is correct, as he's not using the SPContext.Web but webs in the AllWebs collection, which need manual disposal.

Comment: I have only dabbled in creating web parts in Visual Studio.  How can I get this code to display the data it generates?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example of how to use it with a visual webpart

Comment: hey could you possible help me out with a small problem?

This line: var eForms = new List<EForm>();

Gives this error:

The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I know it's probably a simple fix, and I am really showing my noobness with this, but could you direct me as to what may be wrong here?

Comment: make sure you have the correct using statement: using System.Collections.Generic;